# How to retrieve domain name via javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

When I used the below script in `www.example.com/about-us/user` , it showed entire url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     alert(document.URL);
</script>
```

I want to get only the domain name in here,say `example.com` .. Is there any javascript inbuilt function for retrieving domain name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
 alert(document.domain);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
alert(document.domain);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(location.hostname);
```

or

```
alert(document.domain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
alert(window.location.host)
```